# Que tipo de dados usar para armazenar URIs no banco?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem, uri

Que tipo de dados usar para armazenar URIs no banco de dados, levando em consideração um comprimento da URI indeterminado ou muito grande?

Comment: URLs que passem de 2K não tem muita garantia de que vão funcionar, a não ser em aplicações especificamente escritas pensando nisso. A RFC recomenta no mínimo suporte a 8K, mas até o IE10, não era possível passar dos 2K na barra de endereço. Mais detalhes aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers - Sugeriria pensar no que sua aplicação vai precisar de fato, limitar o valor e documentar corretamente.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101

Comment: Uma boa duvida Vinícius +1

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Armazenar dados na base de dados usando o PDO::commit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51655/armazenar-dados-na-base-de-dados-usando-o-pdocommit)

Comment: @Gonçalo as perguntas não tem relação alguma, poderia verificar se indicou o link certo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se considerar que URLs não costumam passar de 2K de tamanho e que o `VARCHAR` no MySQL suporta até 65535 caracteres (a linha também tem esse limite, então na prática tem que ser um pouco menor. Isso dá com sobras.

Em teoria um URL pode ter tamanho maior, então se quiser garantir mesmo seria interessante usar um `MEDIUMTEXT` (16MB) ou `LONGTEXT` (4GB). Mas eu acho uma grande bobagem, eu iria de `VARCHAR` mesmo, até que se prove que precisa de algo maior.

Obviamente descarto qualquer tipo que não seja texto, pelo menos no MySQL.

Mais detalhes em [Quais os tipos de dados existentes no MySQL para textos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78812/101).

A pergunta originalmente falava em URL e depois mudou para URI. Ainda vale o mesmo. Tem mais chance de URI passar do tamanho de um `VARCHAR`, mas dependendo de como for composta o URI a solução melhor seria outra.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).